# Get the second eval (regex with wildcards)?

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading an HTML document. So far I have been using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) with [`HTML::Element`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement) and `look_down`, but now I am stuck with the content of a script `<script>...</script>`

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('7 F={f:"P+/=",Q:z(5){7 8="";7 s,k,l,v,t,h,j;7 i=0;5=F.I(5);G(i<5.B){s=5.m(i++);k=5.m(i++);l=5.m(i++);v=s>>2;t=((s&3)<<4)|(k>>4);h=((k&H)<<2)|(l>>6);j=l&u;o(J(k)){h=j=C}w o(J(l)){j=C}8=8+p.f.q(v)+p.f.q(t)+p.f.q(h)+p.f.q(j)}D 8},R:z(5){7 8="";7 s,k,l;7 v,t,h,j;7 i=0;5=5.K(/[^A-S-T-9\\+\\/\\=]/g,"");G(i<5.B){v=p.f.E(5.q(i++));t=p.f.E(5.q(i++));h=p.f.E(5.q(i++));j=p.f.E(5.q(i++));s=(v<<2)|(t>>4);k=((t&H)<<4)|(h>>2);l=((h&3)<<6)|j;8=8+b.d(s);o(h!=C){8=8+b.d(k)}o(j!=C){8=8+b.d(l)}}8=F.L(8);D 8},I:z(e){e=e.K(/\\r\\n/g,"\\n");7 a="";U(7 n=0;n<e.B;n++){7 c=e.m(n);o(c<x){a+=b.d(c)}w o((c>V)&&(c<W)){a+=b.d((c>>6)|X);a+=b.d((c&u)|x)}w{a+=b.d((c>>M)|N);a+=b.d(((c>>6)&u)|x);a+=b.d((c&u)|x)}}D a},L:z(a){7 e="";7 i=0;7 c=Y=y=0;G(i<a.B){c=a.m(i);o(c<x){e+=b.d(c);i++}w o((c>Z)&&(c<N)){y=a.m(i+1);e+=b.d(((c&10)<<6)|(y&u));i+=2}w{y=a.m(i+1);O=a.m(i+2);e+=b.d(((c&H)<<M)|((y&u)<<6)|(O&u));i+=3}}D e}}',62,63,'|||||input||var|output||utftext|String||fromCharCode|string|_keyStr||enc3||enc4|chr2|chr3|charCodeAt||if|this|charAt||chr1|enc2|63|enc1|else|128|c2|function||length|64|return|indexOf|Base64|while|15|_utf8_encode|isNaN|replace|_utf8_decode|12|224|c3|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789|encode|decode|Za|z0|for|127|2048|192|c1|191|31'.split('|'),0,{}));
    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(c/a))+String.fromCharCode(c%a+161)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\[\xa1-\xff]+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp(e(c),'g'),k[c])}}return p}('¦ £=\'¥+¢+¤+¢+\';¡.«();¡.§(©.¨(£));¡.ª();',11,11,'document|PC9pZnJhbWU|ba2se|PGlmcmFtZSB3aWR0aCA9ICIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQgPSAiMTAwJSIgc2Nyb2xsaW5nID0gImF1dG8iIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyID0gIjAiIHNyYz0iJiMxMDQ7JiMxMTY7JiMxMTY7JiMxMTI7JiM1ODsmIzQ3OyYjNDc7JiMxMTc7JiMxMDg7JiM0NjsmIzExNjsmIzExMTsmIzQ3OyYjNTY7JiMxMTQ7JiM5ODsmIzEyMTsmIzExNzsmIzU3OyYjMTEzOyYjMTAwOyI|PGlmcmFtZSB3aWR0aCA9ICIwIiBoZWlnaHQgPSAiMCIgc2Nyb2xsaW5nID0gImF1dG8iIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyID0gIjAiIHNyYz0iaHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5kZSI|var|write|decode|Base64|close|open'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script>
```

I want to get the text from the second `eval` eval(......) to

I tried

```
my ($var) = $response->decoded_content =~ /^eval(.*?)\/script/
```

but I get both evals, which is obvious.

**EDIT** : Added raw source

Comment: What are you using to produce a string that contains `<script>` tags? Calls like `as_text` will remove all HTML tags, and you should be processing the contents of `<script>` elements as simple text strings.

Comment: Since the source code of the page isn't long, I use `decoded_content` to get the whole html code, but the probleme no seems to be the wildcards, i will put the content of both evals in my edit

Comment: `decoded_content` is nothing to do with `HTML::TreeBuilder` or `look_down`. You are simply fetching the contents of the HTML page, before it is parsed by `HTML::TreeBuilder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program shows how you might go about it. `/eval/` finds the *first* occurrence of `eval`, while `/.*eval/` find the *last* occurrence.

I have used an HTML document that is empty apart from a single `<script>` element in the `<head>` section.

The call to `look_down` will find *all* `<script>` elements with a `language` attribute equal to `JavaScript` and put them in the array `@script`. In this case there is only one, so I use `$script[0]`. Depending on your HTML you may need to select one of several elements.

A call to `as_text` ignores `<script>` and `<style>` elements, so I have to use `content_list` to get the text inside the `<script>` element. This text is put into `$content`, and everything from the *last* occurrence of `eval` onwards is copied to `$eval`.

I hope this helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);
my @script = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'script', language => 'JavaScript');
my ($content) = $script[0]->content_list;
my ($eval) = $content =~ /.*(eval.+\S)/s;
print $eval;

__DATA__
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('7 F={f:"P+/=",Q:z(5){7 8="";7 s,k,l,v,t,h,j;7 i=0;5=F.I(5);G(i<5.B){s=5.m(i++);k=5.m(i++);l=5.m(i++);v=s>>2;t=((s&3)<<4)|(k>>4);h=((k&H)<<2)|(l>>6);j=l&u;o(J(k)){h=j=C}w o(J(l)){j=C}8=8+p.f.q(v)+p.f.q(t)+p.f.q(h)+p.f.q(j)}D 8},R:z(5){7 8="";7 s,k,l;7 v,t,h,j;7 i=0;5=5.K(/[^A-S-T-9\\+\\/\\=]/g,"");G(i<5.B){v=p.f.E(5.q(i++));t=p.f.E(5.q(i++));h=p.f.E(5.q(i++));j=p.f.E(5.q(i++));s=(v<<2)|(t>>4);k=((t&H)<<4)|(h>>2);l=((h&3)<<6)|j;8=8+b.d(s);o(h!=C){8=8+b.d(k)}o(j!=C){8=8+b.d(l)}}8=F.L(8);D 8},I:z(e){e=e.K(/\\r\\n/g,"\\n");7 a="";U(7 n=0;n<e.B;n++){7 c=e.m(n);o(c<x){a+=b.d(c)}w o((c>V)&&(c<W)){a+=b.d((c>>6)|X);a+=b.d((c&u)|x)}w{a+=b.d((c>>M)|N);a+=b.d(((c>>6)&u)|x);a+=b.d((c&u)|x)}}D a},L:z(a){7 e="";7 i=0;7 c=Y=y=0;G(i<a.B){c=a.m(i);o(c<x){e+=b.d(c);i++}w o((c>Z)&&(c<N)){y=a.m(i+1);e+=b.d(((c&10)<<6)|(y&u));i+=2}w{y=a.m(i+1);O=a.m(i+2);e+=b.d(((c&H)<<M)|((y&u)<<6)|(O&u));i+=3}}D e}}',62,63,'|||||input||var|output||utftext|String||fromCharCode|string|_keyStr||enc3||enc4|chr2|chr3|charCodeAt||if|this|charAt||chr1|enc2|63|enc1|else|128|c2|function||length|64|return|indexOf|Base64|while|15|_utf8_encode|isNaN|replace|_utf8_decode|12|224|c3|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789|encode|decode|Za|z0|for|127|2048|192|c1|191|31'.split('|'),0,{}));    
      eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(c/a))+String.fromCharCode(c%a+161)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\[\xa1-\xff]+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp(e(c),'g'),k[c])}}return p}('¦ £=\'¥+¢+¤+¢+\';¡.«();¡.§(©.¨(£));¡.ª();',11,11,'document|PC9pZnJhbWU|ba2se|PGlmcmFtZSB3aWR0aCA9ICIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQgPSAiMTAwJSIgc2Nyb2xsaW5nID0gImF1dG8iIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyID0gIjAiIHNyYz0iJiMxMDQ7JiMxMTY7JiMxMTY7JiMxMTI7JiM1ODsmIzQ3OyYjNDc7JiMxMTc7JiMxMDg7JiM0NjsmIzExNjsmIzExMTsmIzQ3OyYjNTY7JiMxMTQ7JiM5ODsmIzEyMTsmIzExNzsmIzU3OyYjMTEzOyYjMTAwOyI|PGlmcmFtZSB3aWR0aCA9ICIwIiBoZWlnaHQgPSAiMCIgc2Nyb2xsaW5nID0gImF1dG8iIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyID0gIjAiIHNyYz0iaHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5kZSI|var|write|decode|Base64|close|open'.split('|'),0,{}))
    </script>
  </head>
  <body> </body>
</html>
```

**output**

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(c/a))+String.fromCharCode(c%a+161)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\[\xa1-\xff]+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp(e(c),'g'),k[c])}}return p}('Â¦ Â£=\'Â¥+Â¢+Â¤+Â¢+\';Â¡.Â«();Â¡.Â§(Â©.Â¨(Â£));Â¡.Âª();',11,11,'document|PC9pZnJhbWU|ba2se|PGlmcmFtZSB3aWR0aCA9ICIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQgPSAiMTAwJSIgc2Nyb2xsaW5nID0gImF1dG8iIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyID0gIjAiIHNyYz0iJiMxMDQ7JiMxMTY7JiMxMTY7JiMxMTI7JiM1ODsmIzQ3OyYjNDc7JiMxMTc7JiMxMDg7JiM0NjsmIzExNjsmIzExMTsmIzQ3OyYjNTY7JiMxMTQ7JiM5ODsmIzEyMTsmIzExNzsmIzU3OyYjMTEzOyYjMTAwOyI|PGlmcmFtZSB3aWR0aCA9ICIwIiBoZWlnaHQgPSAiMCIgc2Nyb2xsaW5nID0gImF1dG8iIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyID0gIjAiIHNyYz0iaHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5kZSI|var|write|decode|Base64|close|open'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: O_O ... just ... THANKS A LOOOOOOT T_T

Comment: @Mugiwara: There was a bug in my original version. I have had to add a `/s` modifier to the regex so that it would look beyond the first newline. It works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern

```
\beval\(.*\S(?!.*eval)(?=\s*<\/script>)
```

or

```
\beval\(.*\K\beval\(.*\S(?=\s*<\/script>)
```

Comment: If the OP is using `HTML::Element` then there are no tags in the string being parsed

Comment: @Borodin - I was thinking about the same, but because OP claims that tags are part of the string, I assume he is using a different approach or he is just adding those tags into string manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just match it twice:

```
/^.*?eval\([^)]+\).*?(eval\([^)]+\))/
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/mP0iK6)

Comment: You saved my day, i am still a noob with regex, thanks a loooot

Comment: yeah my bad, the code body is sooooo long that is hy i didnt put here

Comment: @Mugiwara: Did this solution work for you, or Ωmega's? It is important that answers are marked correctly, as many other people will come here for a solution to problems like yours.

Comment: Neither one, wait check my edit, i didnt put the content of both evals in the beginning cuz i thought it will be irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

For now this one works for me

```
 /eval\(function\(p,a,c,k,e,d\)\{.*\}\)\)/gmsi
```

Thank you all for your help, i did a mistake by not putting the whole script content in the beginning.